# Change css with how many elements are in Meteor collection.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

So I am building an application that will allow the user to store equations and have it on a homepage, where the user will be able to have a button appear with the title "Equation". So my issue is that I would like to display these buttons differently depending on how many there are. I want to have one row on the main page and have the buttons style themselves like so

If only one button:

....................................|button|....................................

If two buttons:

.....................|button|.....................|button|.....................

If three buttons:

.............|button|.............|button|.............|button|..........

I've looked online and I'm not sure where to start to add this functionality. So my question is where can I start to add this functionality? Thank you.

Comment: if you edit your question and include the codes on how you generate your buttons, I can write you an answer that will work. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly; you have something like this in your HTML-Code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <button>Equation</button>
        <button>Equation</button>
    </div>
```

Then in your CSS-Code you could add this and it will center all the Elements in your row, change the width of the button as you need:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

button {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Explanation: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Comment: I dont understand your comment, he wanted to style the buttons like his example, he didnt make it yet, perhaps I didnt understand his question